# How to remove a simple body in JBox2D?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, jbox2d

Whenever I try to destroy a body in JBox2D it always give me a NullPointerException, and I have checked online and they show various ways of doing it 'safely' which I don't understand. I was wondering if anyone could type up some simple pseudo code to show how you would destroy a body in Box2D. I am also using the LibGDX API as well.

Here is my code that I use:

```
public void render(float delta) {

    if(bodiesContainer.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Body body:bodiesContainer)
        {
            world.destroyBody(body);
        }
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();


    world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITYITERATIONS, POSITIONITERATIONS);

    camera.update();

    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    batch.end();

}

 public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/5, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);
    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0f), true);
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    stage = new Stage();

    particleCreator = new ParticleCreator(0, 0, 1);
    particleCreator.destroyParticle(world, particleBody);

    if (particleCreator == null)
    {
        System.out.println("true");
    }

    if (particleBody == null)
    {
        System.out.println("true particleBody");
    }

    if (particleBodyDef == null)
    {
        System.out.println("true particleBodyDef");
    }


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            switch(keycode) {
            case Keys.SPACE:

                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public class ParticleCreator 
{   



//Default constructor
public ParticleCreator()
{

}

public ParticleCreator(World world, BodyDef bodyDef, Body body, float position_x, float position_y, float particle_radius)
{
    bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(position_x, position_y);

    CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
    circleShape.setRadius(particle_radius);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0;

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
}

public void destroyParticle(World world, Body body)
{
    world.destroyBody(body);
    System.out.println("This Particle has been destroyed !!!");
}

}
```

The bodiesContainer is an ArrayList, and the particleBody is a JBox2D body i wish to destroy, but every time I press the space button it crashes and gives me a NullPointerException.

Comment: Why are you talking about JBox2D bodies? It seems to be a standard libgdx core class. Are you really running it in the browser via GWT and this is a platform specific JBox2D problem? Also it would be nice if you could tell what exactly causes the null pointer. Which object is `null`?

Comment: Yeh sorry I was meant to say libgdx bodies, I am running this on eclipse as well. I decided to be more structured with my programming and I decided to use a separate class for the particlebody, which is why I created the particleCreator class. Howeever when I put some print test statements I find that my particleBody is null, which I don't understand. I have reedited and included the necessary code above. And the exception occurs on this line particleCreator.destroyParticle(world, particleBody);

Comment: Dont use print statements for something like this. Learn how to use the debugger. Set a breakpoint at the important places and run through your code step by step and check why it becomes `null`.

Comment: I don't know how to use it but is it possible for you to point out where I have gone wrong ?

Comment: I know particleBody is null but I don't know why

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You destroy this particleBody in the show method without ever setting it to any value. It is always null.